# foreach loop only repeating last array value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays.

ArrayA is numeric

```
(ArrayA => 3, 7, 8)
```

ArrayB is an associative array

```
(1=>bread, 2=>banana, 3=>fruit, 4=> milk, 5=>pizza, 6=> gum, 7=>corn, 8=>lager)
```

I want to create a third array, ArrayC, associative, that matches the Values of ArrayA with ArrayB keys, and gives ArrayA keys the relevant ArrayB values.

In other words, from this example

```
ArrayC (3 => fruit, 7=>corn, 8=>lager)
```

However my code is only giving me

```
ArrayC (3 => lager, 7=>lager, 8=>lager) //last value of ArrayB
```

Code:

```
     $ArrayC = array();
     foreach ($ArrayB as $keyB => $valueB) {
          foreach ($ArrayA as $valueA) {
             if ( $valueA = $keyB) {
                   $ArrayC [$valueA] = $valueB;
             }
          }
      }
      print_r($ArrayC);
```

Comment: `if` need compare with `==`, not `=` only.

Comment: You probably want `$valueA == $keyB` instead of `$valueA = $keyB`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: `if` need compare with `==`, not with `=` (it set value).

Second: this is a better version of code:

```
// The keys that you want copy from ArrayB
$ArrayA = array(3, 7, 8);
// The values that will be copied
$ArrayB = array(1 => 'bread', 2 => 'banana', 3 => 'fruit',
                4 => 'milk', 5 => 'pizza', 6 => 'gum', 7 => 'corn',
                8 => 'lager');
// The filtered array (based on ArrayA and ArrayB)
$ArrayC = array();

// For each ArrayA values (3, 7 and 8), trigger this routine
// setting ArrayKey as each value of ArrayA, one for time
foreach($ArrayA as $ArrayKey) {
    // Basically: $ArrayC [3] = $ArrayB [3]; (...)
    $ArrayC [$ArrayKey] = $ArrayB [$ArrayKey];
} 

// Final result will be:
// $ArrayC = array( 3 => 'fruit', 7 => 'corn', 8 => 'lager' );
```

Comment: I was thinking of why you just send as comment instead answer :)

Comment: It was a simple answer, fit in a comment. I think that is better a more robust answer (exemplified), I did it now, but other user can do for me, in future, because of my comment. :)

Comment: @David, right on both counts and you're second answer is sooo elegant for a newbie like me that i'll have to write 10 lines of comment to be able to understand it in the future!!!

Comment: I have commented for you to understand better how it works. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$common_keys = array_intersect($ArrayA, array_keys($ArrayB));
$arrayC = array();
foreach($common_keys as $key) {
   $arrayC[$key] = $ArrayB[$key];
}
```

Comment: I endorse this code-only answer to a typo question.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one loop:

```
      foreach ($ArrayA as $valueA) {
         $ArrayC [$valueA] = $arrayB[$valueA];
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayC=Array()
foreach($arrayA as $valueA){
   $arrayC[$valueA]=$arrayB[$valueA];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing lowercase/uppercase variable names. You'll want to use `$valueB` instead of `$ValueB`.

Also, in your `if` you are assigning, not comparing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without looping through the arrays, you could try using a combination of [array_intersect_key()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [array_flip()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

```
$ArrayA = array(3, 7, 8);
$ArrayB = array(1 => 'bread', 2 => 'banana', 3 => 'fruit',
            4 => 'milk', 5 => 'pizza', 6 => 'gum', 7 => 'corn',
            8 => 'lager');
$searchArray = array_flip( $ArrayA );
$results = array_intersect_key( $ArrayB, $searchArray );

var_dump( $results );
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a better way to do it:

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Comment: ...except that it doesn't do what the OP wants. Try it with the example arrays he provided.

Comment: manual says for array_combine;  Returns the combined array, FALSE if the number of elements for each array isn't equal.

Comment: for array combine you need equal no of variables in both arrays.